# multiprocessing less effective regular code

Tags: python, performance, optimization, multiprocessing

I have a resource-intensive function that I want to execute as quickly as possible. So I tried with multiprocessing but the function takes longer to execute and consumes more CPU resources than without multiprocessing and the other problem is that the CPU never reach 100% utilisation even if the computation time is very long and was supposed be executed on 4 cores.

Feel also free to propose other optimizations than with multiprocessing if you want.

```
import random
import multiprocessing
import time


def generate_and_sum_random_numbers(num_elements):
    random_numbers = [random.randint(0, 100) for i in range(num_elements)]
    total_sum = sum(random_numbers)
    print(num_elements)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    start = time.time()
    CPU_core_number = 4
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=CPU_core_number)

    for i in range(3000):
        pool.apply(generate_and_sum_random_numbers, args=(i,))

    stop = time.time()
    print("Time needed:", stop-start)
```

Comment: `pool.apply()` blocks until the task is complete, you are not running tasks in parallel , try `apply_async` instead to run tasks in parallel https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.apply

Comment: side note: use `numpy` to "generate_and_sum_random_numbers"

Answer (score 0):

For processing a 1-argument function in parallel and collecting the results, use `pool.map`.  Below I've created predictable CPU-bound "work" using a spin wait of .25 second.  If 8 processes are used, 320 items should be processed in parallel in 320/8*.25 (10) seconds:

```py
import multiprocessing
import time

def worker(i):
    # spinwait to use CPU for .25 second.
    start = time.perf_counter()
    while time.perf_counter() - start < .25:
        pass
    return i * 2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.perf_counter()
    with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
        results = pool.map(worker, range(320))
    stop = time.perf_counter()
    print(results)
    print("Time needed:", stop - start)
```

Output:

```
[0, 2, 4, 6, ..., 632, 634, 636, 638]
Time needed: 10.395985100010876
```

[image: CPU utilization]

Using the OP's example, and collecting a result instead of printing it:

```
import random
import multiprocessing
import time

def generate_and_sum_random_numbers(num_elements):
    random_numbers = [random.randint(0, 100) for i in range(num_elements)]
    total_sum = sum(random_numbers)
    #print(total_sum)
    return total_sum

if __name__ == '__main__':

    start = time.perf_counter()
    CPU_core_number = 4
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=CPU_core_number)
    results = pool.map(generate_and_sum_random_numbers, range(3000))
    stop = time.perf_counter()
    print(results)
    print("Time needed:", stop-start)
```

Output:

```
[0, 85, 30, 85, ..., 146916, 148838, 148574, 148476]
Time needed: 1.4560908999992535
```

With `print` uncommented.  It affects timing a bit.

```
C:\Users\metolone>test
0
17
81
75
...
153428
149615
149069
150249
[0, 17, 81, 75, ..., 153428, 149615, 149069, 150249]
Time needed: 2.1174581999948714
```

Comment: They're not trying to collect results. What's the proper way for that?

Comment: `print` in the worker really affects the timing since it has to be serialized to the terminal.  `map` collects the return values of the workers in the order submitted, which is what I have shown above (`apply` returns the result as well, OP just didn't save the result). 
 This shows off the parallelism better.

Comment: *"print in the worker really affects the timing"* - Does it? With or without print, their code takes me about 6.8 seconds. Doesn't make a dent. I'd be more interested in seeing theirs fixed than in an example that has nothing to do with it anymore...

Comment: (I know map, but don't know the proper way to do what they're trying)

Comment: (And I suspect creating on average 1500 random numbers is enough work for proper multiprocessing being faster)

Comment: @KellyBundy Updated.  Is that what you wanted to see?

Comment: I got 4.9s (5.33 with print) using `results = [pool.apply(generate_and_sum_random_numbers, args=(i,)) for i in range(3000)]`, which ends up serializing the use of the pool since each `apply` waits for the result, so multiprocessing with `map` definitely has an affect.

Comment: Better, thanks. But it's still mapping, and I wonder what to do if one really doesn't have a `return`. Oh well. One day I'll find the time to read the doc. I guess this suffices to demonstrate that actual multiprocessing is faster. Or at least it would, if you included the time for the same work without multiprocessing. (The question really should show both times as well, bothers me when they complain about something being slower but they don't even share the times.)